# Difficulty Manipulating QSlider in a QGridLayout

Tags: qt, qt4, qslider

I'm trying to create a dynamic QSlider that accepts a QVector of integer values and maps them underneath the QSlider relative to what position they represent.

Here's a screenshot of what I have now:
[My Slider http://dev.kyleswebspace.com/images/QInteractiveSlider.jpg](http://dev.kyleswebspace.com/images/QInteractiveSlider.jpg)

As you can see, the ticks don't line up with their values. This is one of the issues.

The main issue I'm struggling with though, is that no matter what I change my PADDING value to (see qinteractiveslider.h), the QSlider in my widget remains the same size in relation to the grid of values.

1. Why isn't my QGridLayout's arguments
   providing the correct amount of
   padding?
2. How can I enforce these margins on
   the QSlider?
3. Is there a better way of positioning
   these labels? I'm open to
   suggestions.

Here is the code:

**qinteractiveslider.h**

```
#ifndef QINTERACTIVESLIDER_H
#define QINTERACTIVESLIDER_H

#include <QtGui/QGridLayout>
#include <QtGui/QLabel>
#include <QtGui/QSlider>
#include <QtGui/QWidget>

class QInteractiveSlider : public QWidget
 {
     Q_OBJECT

public:
    QInteractiveSlider(QVector<int>* values, int min, int max, QWidget *parent = 0, Qt::WFlags flags = 0);
    ~QInteractiveSlider();

private:
    static const int GRID_WIDTH = 10000;
    static const int PADDING = GRID_WIDTH / 3;

    QGridLayout* m_layout;
    QSlider* m_slider;
    QVector<int>* m_values;
};
```

**qinteractiveslider.cpp**

```
#include "qinteractiveslider.h"

QInteractiveSlider::QInteractiveSlider(QVector<int>* values, int min, int max, QWidget *parent, Qt::WFlags flags)
    : QWidget(parent, flags)
{
    m_layout = new QGridLayout();
    m_layout->setSpacing(0);

    m_slider = new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal);
    m_slider->setTickInterval(25);
    m_slider->setTickPosition(QSlider::TicksBelow);

    m_layout->addWidget(m_slider, 0, PADDING, 1, GRID_WIDTH - PADDING, Qt::AlignBottom);

    //populate bottom row with labels
    QVector<int>::Iterator iterator = values->begin();
    while(iterator != values->end()) {
        //place the label at the relative position under the slider
        int columnIndex = ((double)*iterator / (double)max) * (double)GRID_WIDTH;
        QString labelString = QString::number(*iterator);
        QLabel* label = new QLabel(labelString);
        m_layout->addWidget(label, 1, columnIndex, 1, 1, Qt::AlignTop);

        iterator++;
    }

    this->setLayout(m_layout);
}

QInteractiveSlider::~QInteractiveSlider()
{

}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "qinteractiveslider.h"
#include <QtGui/QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QVector<int>* testVector = new QVector<int>();
    testVector->append(0);
    testVector->append(50);
    testVector->append(25);
    testVector->append(100);

    QInteractiveSlider* w = new QInteractiveSlider(testVector, 0, 100);
    w->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: I ended up going with Liz's suggestion and it worked great. Thanks Liz!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that a grid layout is the best way to go about this.

Firstly, I would let the slider take care of itself - in a layout.  And then the big job would be to place the labels where they should go.

Instead of using a layout for this, I would just parent the labels to the parent QWidget and then call

QWidget::move(int x, int y)

However, this will only work the first time, but since you are very nicely isolated in a QWidget (custom control) you can re-adjust the label positions when the parent resizes as follows:

```
void QInteractiveSlider::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
   QWidget::resizeEvent(event);

   //  Loop through the labels and adjust their location.
   label->move(...);
}
```

That should do the trick.

If you run across any problems with this, let me know, and we'll see what we can do.

Comment: This is the method I ended up going with and it worked fantastically. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot directly answer the 1st and 2nd questions.
Displaying numbers separately is a bad idea. Since now you have to know where to manually display the numbers. This is not very portable and breaks encapsulation. It also might not scale properly to changing QSlider sizes.
Since QSlider doesn't give an option of displaying numbers under ticks , you should either extend QSlider and rewrite the paint() function or use QWT. http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_slider.html

Comment: I have to also be able to make these displayed numbers clickable so that clicking on a number adjusts the slider. How can I accomplish this if I go the route of overriding paint()?

Answer (score 0):

You could also perhaps use a combination of QHBoxLayouts instead that way you could space things properly without too much hassle with the margins.

Here is a screenshot of what the following code produces:

[image]

You could make it a bit prettier by putting a maximum width on the labels.  That way you could avoid having to set the left align right align on them.

```
#ifndef DESIGNERLS7532_H
#define DESIGNERLS7532_H

#include <QtCore/QVariant>
#include <QtGui/QAction>
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtGui/QButtonGroup>
#include <QtGui/QHBoxLayout>
#include <QtGui/QHeaderView>
#include <QtGui/QLabel>
#include <QtGui/QSlider>
#include <QtGui/QVBoxLayout>
#include <QtGui/QWidget>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

class Ui_Form
{
public:
    QVBoxLayout *verticalLayout;
    QWidget *widget;
    QHBoxLayout *horizontalLayout;
    QSlider *horizontalSlider;
    QWidget *widget_2;
    QHBoxLayout *horizontalLayout_2;
    QLabel *label;
    QLabel *label_4;
    QLabel *label_2;
    QLabel *label_5;
    QLabel *label_3;

    void setupUi(QWidget *Form)
    {
        if (Form->objectName().isEmpty())
            Form->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("Form"));
        Form->resize(268, 55);
        verticalLayout = new QVBoxLayout(Form);
        verticalLayout->setSpacing(0);
        verticalLayout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        verticalLayout->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("verticalLayout"));
        widget = new QWidget(Form);
        widget->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("widget"));
        horizontalLayout = new QHBoxLayout(widget);
        horizontalLayout->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"));
        horizontalLayout->setContentsMargins(-1, -1, -1, 0);
        horizontalSlider = new QSlider(widget);
        horizontalSlider->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("horizontalSlider"));
        horizontalSlider->setOrientation(Qt::Horizontal);
        horizontalSlider->setTickPosition(QSlider::TicksBelow);

        horizontalLayout->addWidget(horizontalSlider);


        verticalLayout->addWidget(widget);

        widget_2 = new QWidget(Form);
        widget_2->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("widget_2"));
        horizontalLayout_2 = new QHBoxLayout(widget_2);
        horizontalLayout_2->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_2"));
        horizontalLayout_2->setContentsMargins(-1, 0, -1, -1);
        label = new QLabel(widget_2);
        label->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("label"));

        horizontalLayout_2->addWidget(label);

        label_4 = new QLabel(widget_2);
        label_4->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("label_4"));
        label_4->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeading|Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignVCenter);

        horizontalLayout_2->addWidget(label_4);

        label_2 = new QLabel(widget_2);
        label_2->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("label_2"));
        label_2->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);

        horizontalLayout_2->addWidget(label_2);

        label_5 = new QLabel(widget_2);
        label_5->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("label_5"));
        label_5->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing|Qt::AlignVCenter);

        horizontalLayout_2->addWidget(label_5);

        label_3 = new QLabel(widget_2);
        label_3->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("label_3"));
        label_3->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing|Qt::AlignVCenter);

        horizontalLayout_2->addWidget(label_3);

        horizontalLayout_2->setStretch(0, 1);
        horizontalLayout_2->setStretch(1, 1);
        horizontalLayout_2->setStretch(2, 1);
        horizontalLayout_2->setStretch(3, 1);
        horizontalLayout_2->setStretch(4, 1);

        verticalLayout->addWidget(widget_2);


        retranslateUi(Form);

        QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(Form);
    } // setupUi

    void retranslateUi(QWidget *Form)
    {
        Form->setWindowTitle(QApplication::translate("Form", "Form", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
        label->setText(QApplication::translate("Form", "0", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
        label_4->setText(QApplication::translate("Form", "25", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
        label_2->setText(QApplication::translate("Form", "50", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
        label_5->setText(QString());
        label_3->setText(QApplication::translate("Form", "100", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
    } // retranslateUi

};

namespace Ui {
    class Form: public Ui_Form {};
} // namespace Ui

QT_END_NAMESPACE

#endif // DESIGNERLS7532_H
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I need to be able to take an undetermined number of undetermined integers, for an undetermined range (all this information will be passed into the constructor).

Comment: Gotcha.  Would you plan on just growing the size of the slider to compensate for the added integers or filter them out when you got too many? The example shows a static version however you could dynamically add qlabels for integers that you were showing to the horizontalLayout_2.